# Kotlin bad type inference gives overload resolution ambiguity

Tags: kotlin, type-inference, overload-resolution

Consider the overloaded function `foo`:

```
fun foo(i: Int) { /* */ }
fun foo(i_s: Collection<Int>) { /* */ }
```

I get an overload resolution ambiguity error with the following code:

```
val bar = foo(Stream.empty<Int>().collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

> Overload resolution ambiguity:
>   public fun foo(i: Int): Unit defined in ...
>   public fun foo(i_s: Collection): Unit defined in ...

As far as I can tell the resolution should be clear: I am collecting the stream to a list, so the `foo(Collection<Int>)` should be taken. Some more experiments suggest a failure to resolve the generics correctly, so:

1. Why does the generics resolution fail in this case?
2. Is this "flaw" documented somewhere? Is this a bug I should report?

I tested a few other things: `foo(listOf())` does not error, neither does

```
val bar = Stream.empty<Int>().collect(Collectors.toList())
val baz = foo(bar)
```

Replacing `toList()` with `toSet()` does not alter the behavior, but `toCollection { ArrayList<Int>() }` compiles in all cases.

If I change `foo` to `fun <T> foo(i_s: Collection<T>)`, the error changes to

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is (Mutable)List! but Int was expected

This opens more questions for me:

3. Why does the resolution work if I store the intermediate result in a variable? After all, its type is resolved automatically as well?
4. What does the type inference error mean? Why does it occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in the old inference algorithm, because it works correctly with the new inference. I filed an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32548) in the Kotlin bug tracker, at least for adding a regression test. You can follow it for updates.

More information on new inference:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31507

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/06/kotlin-1-3-40-released/